# How can I debug issues in VimL?

Tags: debugging, vim

I'd like to know more about debugging in vim. What features does vim have that can help me to diagnose a problem I might have?

I'd basically like to know:

- How can I diagnose a problem with my `.vimrc` and other configuration files?
- What are some strategies to debugging a script in VimL?

Comment: `:help debug-scripts`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How can I diagnose a problem with .vimrc and other configuration files?

If you're having some unexpected behavior in vim and you're not sure where the
problem is originating, there are a few approaches to honing in on the source
of the issue. One of the best first steps is to find out if your problem is
normal vim behavior, caused by a plugin or caused by your `.vimrc`.

If your vim instance is setting a particular `'option'` and you're not sure
where it is being set. You can use the `:verbose` command to find out. For
instance

```
:verbose set nocompatible?
nocompatible
     Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

To run an instance of vim without any plugins or configuration files run

```
vim -N -u NONE
```

I set this as to alias called `cleanvim` in my `.bashrc` file. The `-u NONE` is
what's doing the magic here. The `-N` simply puts vim into `nocompatible` mode,
which generally is desired. You can also use the option `NORC` to only exclude
your vimrc. Note that if you use something like pathogen or vundle to
instantiate your plugins from within your vimrc, then your plugins will also
not load properly.

If you are using a plugin manager like pathogen or vundle then excluding your
plugins is simple; just comment out the line in your `.vimrc` that calls
pathogen or vundle. However if you have other plugins loaded from your `.vim`
directory you can exclude them with the `--noplugin` flag.

If your problem is being caused by a plugin, try adding back plugins one by one
to determine which one is causing the issue. From there you can either report
the bug to the plugin's maintainer or try to diagnose the problem yourself
using the tips from the rest of this answer.

If your problem is caused by your `.vimrc` there are some ways to hone in on
the problem further. Once simple method is to add the `finish` command at some
point in your `.vimrc`. Once this command is encountered the script will stop
being sourced and no commands after it will be executed. In this way you can
exclude large portions of your `.vimrc` and try to find out the general region
where the problem is coming from.

### What are some strategies to debugging a script in VimL?

Vim has a help section on this topic at `:h debug-scripts`. This describes
vim's debug mode in detail, which will allow you to set breakpoints and step
through a sourced file or user function. You can add a breakpoint on a specific
function or a specific line in a file. For instance...

```
" set a breakpoint on the function MyCoolFunc
:breakadd func MyCoolFunc

" set a breakpoint on line 43 of your .vimrc
:breakadd file 43 .vimrc

" set a breakpoint at this location
:breakadd here
```

After you set a breakpoint you can source the file again to begin debug mode at
that line. If you'd like to use debug mode on an entire file start vim with the
`-D` flag. You could also run debug mode on a particular command. For example,
say you're having trouble with a particular command `:MyCommand`. You can start
debugging mode on this command with `:debug MyCommand`.

Once debug mode has been started you can use the usual set of vim commands.
This is useful because you can now check the value of variables using the
`echo` command to try and diagnose an issue. You can also use the `verbose`
option to provide extra information about the following lines. See `:h 'verbose'`
for its options.

Comment: There is one note about debugging and verbose that one must know: if any of these results in trying to print a self-referencing list or dictionary then you cannot debug without changing execution flow in `:try` because `string(recursive_dict)` throws. When using `verbose` and any of my plugins it is very common. When using `:debug` this happens if something recursive is returned (vim is sometimes printing messages about what called function return. They are normally silenced, but this is not helpful). I had this problem when debugging NERDTree.

Comment: You reminded me that it is good idea to actually report bugs: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/tHgJGG1u0DI.

Answer (score 3):

[The scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) is very helpful to debug vimL:

- provide commands for easier insertion of Vim breakpoints
- `:Runtime` allows easy reload of plugins, even unleting include guards
- `:Disarm {file}`: attempt to disable a runtime file by removing its mappings, commands and autocmds
- `:Time {command}`: profilling
- `:Verbose {command}`: like `:verbose`, but capture the results to a file and load it in the preview window

For cases where you need to restart Vim several times (e.g.: incremental removal of plugins) the `:RestartVim` command of [session plugin](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session) can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

For vimL I find those 2 plugins awesome:

- [BreakPts](https://github.com/albfan/vim-breakpts)

  Set/View Vim breakpoints and browse functions visually
- Decho

  Better echo functionality suitable for debugging scripts

I also use this to quickly source the selected vimL lines:

```
fu! SourceRange() range
  let tmpsofile = tempname()
  call writefile(getline(a:firstline, a:lastline), l:tmpsofile)
  execute "source " . l:tmpsofile
  call delete(l:tmpsofile)
  let n = a:lastline - a:firstline + 1
  echo 'Sourced ' . n . ' line' . (n > 1 ? 's' : '')
endf
com! -range Source <line1>,<line2>call SourceRange()

nn gs m`:Source<cr>``
vn gs m`:Source<cr>``
```